# TextMate - Commands - Change current line number

Tags: textmate

I'm currently trying to create a template in TextMate. The template is very basic:

```
<?php

?>
```

Nothing special. But I want when the template is created, to put the text cursor between the the start and end tag.

I know this can be done with AppleScript, and probably a Macro, and it can probably be done with creating a snippet that executes on creation of the template, but I feel like there should be an easier way.

Any help would be great.

-- Edit --

My complete apologies. A little more googling and I found my answer:

http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/02/snippet-power-templates-in-textmate

Thanks.
Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer by doing a little bit more Googling.

http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/02/snippet-power-templates-in-textmate